# How to disable screen output in ROOT (CERN)

Tags: c++, performance, screen, root-framework

I am fitting curves to the peaks in roughly 25000 detector events.  My code just loops through all of the events, fitting to all peaks it finds and grabbing parameter info.  It takes FOREVER!

I stopped my code from actually drawing the curves, but I'm wondering if I can do anything else to speed up this processing.  I thought that if I stopped ROOT from printing the parameters from each fit to the screen that maybe it would run faster.

Is this true?  If so, how can I do it?  Any other ideas?

```
  TGraphErrors * gr1 = view_waveform_ebars(run,evtNum,21);    
  mygaus -> SetParameters(671.55e3,-1000,S2loc,500);
  gr1 -> Fit(mygaus,"","",tspulse_sum[j],tepulse_sum[j]);
  fitResult = gr1 -> GetFunction("mygaus");

  pchi2[j] =  fitResult -> GetChisquare();
```

I was hoping not to need to copy the functions I'm using into my post.  But `mygaus` has 4 parameters, and every time I call it using `gr1-> Fit(mygaus,...)` I see the parameters on the screen.  So the question is whether or not that screen output is slowing me down, and, if so, how do I turn it off?

Thanks

Comment: It will be more than helpful if you could post some of the relevant code for us to look at.

Comment: What exactly is "ROOT"? Does `gr1->Fit(...)` print to stdout, stderr, /dev/console, or somewhere else? What happens if you redirect the program's output to /dev/null (or your system's equivalent)?

Comment: Have you tried the "Q" option?

Comment: @molbdnilo: That's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also start root with the option -b

```
root -b
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a comment:

There is also the "N" option which forces ROOT to not store the graphics function and not draw anything.

So I would use both, i.e.:

```
gr1 -> Fit(mygaus,"QN","",tspulse_sum[j],tepulse_sum[j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, just maybe, you want to run ROOT in batch mode, like this:

```
{
  gROOT->SetBatch(1);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to limit the general ROOT output using

```
gROOT->ProcessLine( "gErrorIgnoreLevel = 1001;")
```

?

The higher the ignore level the less printout you will get.
To ignore INFO messages, 1001 is enough. To ignore WARNING it has to be above 2001. To ignore ERROR it has to be above 3001. Check what level the printouts are and set it as appropriate.